# Console File Viewer which shows byte position numbers

Tags: grep, less

I have a large data-file with record length 800 bytes. It is to big to open it in gui-texteditors, but less and grep is working fine.

But I need to see fast which number is in the records on position 61 and 451 and so on. Is there a file-viewer or maybe function in less to display the byte numeration within a record?

on mainframe we have something like that:

```
0000000006....6000000001  *000000107024                WDB            N   0 SERV
FFFFFFFFFF0003FFFFFFFFFF445FFFFFFFFFFFF4444444444444444ECC444444444444D444F4ECDE
0000000006000C600000000100C00000010702400000000000000006420000000000005000002595
 ...+...10....+...20....+...30....+...40....+...50....+...60....+...70....+.... 
ICEWÄSCHE 1                                     450SLC                          
CCCE4ECCC4F4444444444444444444444444444444444444FFFEDC44444444444444444444444444
9356A238501000000000000000000000000000000000000045023300000000000000000000000000
 ...+...90....+..100....+..110....+..120....+..130....+..140....+..150....+.... 
    000001000E107024                                                            
4444FFFFFFFFFCFFFFFF444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
00000000010005107024000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 ...+..170....+..180....+..190....+..200....+..210....+..220....+..230....+.... 
  WDB107024.....................................................................
44ECCFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00642107024000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 ...+..250....+..260....+..270....+..280....+..290....+..300....+..310....+....
```

Is there something like that in Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure what your "mainframe" example is supposed to show - can you add a small, testable example of the real input and desired output?

Comment: And are you sure GUI editors can't open it? I often use emacs on files that are several gigabytes in size. Finally, are you just looking for something like `head -c 143 | tail -c1` to see what character is at the 143th byte of the file?

Comment: This example is showing a line of a data file. first row is the character-line, second and third line is the hex-value of this byte and line four is the byte position number to see on which position this byte is located within the record.

at the moment i am working with head and tail like terdon said. but nicer would be to have such a tool to display one line of file.